# joinVoiceChannel is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I set up the new voice channel stuff at the top of my code to define `joinVoiceChannel`.

```js
async execute(message, args) {
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
guildId: message.guild.id, 
adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        });
```

```js
async execute(message, args) {
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.guild.id,
            guildId: message.member.voice.channelId, 
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        });
```

here's the command that actually plays the music:

```js
        if (validURL(args[0])) {
            await joinVoiceChannel({voiceChannel});
            const stream = ytdl(args[0], { filter: 'audioonly' });

            connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 }).on('finish', () => {
                connection.destroy({ timeout: 120000 });
            });
```

I can get the bot to join the vc but I get this error:

```
2021-08-09T20:43:42.613424+00:00 app[Worker.1]:             const connection = await joinVoiceChannel({voiceChannel});
2021-08-09T20:43:42.613425+00:00 app[Worker.1]:                                ^
```

Comment: What is `voice`? And why do you later use the `joinVoiceChannel()` without it? How did you import the `@discordjs/voice` package? And why do you think `joinVoiceChannel()` should be defined, how did you import the function from the package? You should update your question with more details.

Comment: @Skilaurun got it. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm using `adapterCreator` in the second snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

You must have made a mistake at

```js
joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.guild.id,
            guildId: message.member.voice.channelId, 
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })
```

As you can see, you set `channelId` as the guild id, and `guildId` as the channel id. You just have to switch them around

```js
joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
            guildId: message.guild.id, 
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })
```

Comment: I now get an error saying `TypeError: joinVoiceChannel is not a function`

Comment: What exactly is the function you use to join vc?

Comment: `await joinVoiceChannel({voiceChannel});`

Comment: You may have meant to declare that like `const {joinVoiceChannel} = require('@discordjs/voice')` using object destructuring according to what [this](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#creation) shows (object destructuring is not required, you can simple do `const joinVoiceChannel = require('@discordjs/voice').joinVoiceChanel`)

Comment: What does adding the brackets change?

Comment: It does object destructuring which will get the `joinVoiceChannel` property from the @discordjs/voice module

Comment: Now I'm getting `TypeError: adapterCreator is not a function` but I'm getting the bot to join my vc.

Comment: I don’t see you trying to do `adapterCreator()` anywhere in your code